# iOS lossless image editing

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing

I'm working on a photo app for iPhone/iPod.

I'd like to get the raw data from a large image in an iPhone app and perform some pixel manipulation on it and write it back to the disk/gallery.

So far I've been converting the UIImage obtained from image picker to unsigned char pointers using the following technique:

```
CGImageRef imageBuff = [imageBuffer CGImage];//imageBuffer is an UIImage *
CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageBuff));
unsigned char *input_image = (unsigned char *)CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);

//height & width represents the dimensions of the input image

unsigned char *resultant = (unsigned char *)malloc(height*4*width);

for (int i=0; i<height;i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<4*width; j+=4)
    {
        resultant[i*4*width+4*(j/4)+0] = input_image[i*4*width+4*(j/4)];
        resultant[i*4*width+4*(j/4)+1] = input_image[i*4*width+4*(j/4)+1];
        resultant[i*4*width+4*(j/4)+2] = input_image[i*4*width+4*(j/4)+2];
        resultant[i*4*width+4*(j/4)+3] = 255;
    }
}
CFRelease(pixelData);
```

I'm doing all operations on *resultant* and writing it back to disk in the original resolution using:

```
     NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

**I'd like to know:**

1. is the transformation actually lossless?
2. if there's a 20-22 MP image at hand... is it wise to do this operation in a background thread? (chances of crashing etc... I'd like to know the best practice for doing this).
3. is there a better method for implementing this *(getting the pixel data is a necessity here)*?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the method is lossless but i am not sure about 20-22 MP images. I think the Iphone is not at all a suitable choice if i want to edit that big images!

Answer (score 1):

I have been successful in capturing and editing image upto 22 MP using this technique.

Tested this on an iPhone 4s and it worked fine. However, some of the effects I'm using required Core Image filters. It seems like CIFilters do not support more than 16 MP images. the filters will return a blank image if used on an image >16MP.

I'd still like people to comment on lossless large image editing strategies in iOS.